# Cleaning glassfish to avoid failing deployment

Tags: java, glassfish

I used to use Tomcat and in that I used to clean temp folder n etc to avoid `OutOfMemoryError`. Recently I have started using Glassfish so I would like to know what all folders data needs to be deleted before redeploying your application?

In my Glassfish domains there is only one domain, domain1. And there are two nodes in which different applications are deployed. My server is on vagrant built linux virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are asking is the following:

> If I redeploy an application to Glassfish multiple times, this results
>   in an OutOfMemoryError sometimes. Which files/folder do I have to
>   delete before redeploying to avoid the error?

Deleting files or folders won't help here, because the `OutOfMemoryError` is caused when not enough RAM is available for the JVM. To fix it, you'll have to restart the server before redeploying.

Everytime the application gets redeployed, Glassfish should unload all the old classes of the previous application version and load the new classes from the new version of the application. But it often happens, that there are some old references to Java class instances which can't be unloaded, therefore more RAM is needed to load the new classes. After a number of redeployments, there are so many references to old classes, that there is not enough RAM left for the new classes and the `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown.

I couldn't find a way to fix this, you can increase the available RAM for the JVM via `-Xmx` parameter but this will only help until the additional memory is also completely full. As described above, restarting the server before redeploying fixes the issue, but of course this isn't a real solution.